# iOS project fails to recognize Database.database().reference() call to Firebase SDK with error 'unresolved identifier Database'

Tags: ios, database, firebase, sdk, identifier

The problem is there's a pod missing in your Podfile, which contains the 'Database' class/struct from the Firebase SDK, and if you add it the problem will go away and you can continue.

[image: This is a shot of the error occurring when trying to get Firebase SDK to work inside iOS project]

Answer (score 0):

This occurred because the Podfile for Firebase SDK didn't add the pod called:

pod 'Firebase/Database'

The project had only loaded pods called: /Analytics , /Core & /Firestore.

In order for the iOS project to recognize any class/objects named "Database", it has to include the line above in the Podfile.  There are MANY addable components from Firebase's SDK, make sure you have the right ones if "auto-complete" isn't giving you what you want when writing your code!

Solution:
Go to your directory in Terminal.
Type 'open Podfile'
Add: pod 'Firebase/Database' to your project, underneath or above the other pods you've loaded from Firebase.
Save the Podfile, then close it.
run 'pod install' in your project directory
Then re-open your project anew, and insert a line like...

let rootRef = Database.database().reference()